# installing KDE on Lenovo Legion laptop

Tags: lenovo-laptop, kde

I am trying to install KDE Neon on a new Windows 11 Lenovo Legion laptop.  I've seen that I may need to disable fast boot but I can't find that option in the bios.  I have USB boot enabled and a USB flash drive with the KDE Neon installation plugged in, however when it boots it just goes directly to windows instead of giving me the KDE install option.  How can I get this installed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of pitfalls that can happen when trying to install Linux on newer machines.  Make sure your disks are set for AHCI in BIOS.  Some manufacturers have it set to RAID, which will prevent installation.  Also, make sure when booting to enter the boot menu when booting up the machine.  On Lenovo laptops, it will be <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.  Select the UEFI boot option for the USB drive.  If it fails, you might need to disable Secure Boot and if available, boot in legacy BIOS mode.